# Operating on a screenshot with Aforge

Tags: c#, screenshot, aforge

I'm trying to take a screenshot using this command:

```
var bmpScreenshot = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width,
                               Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height,
                               PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

            var gfxScreenshot = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenshot);
            gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X,
                                        Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y,
                                        0,
                                        0,
                                        Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size,
                                        CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
```

Then i'd like to find if another image is contained into the screenshot (im using AForge).

The problem is that my variable gfxScreenshot is not accepted by AForge.

Using the following command and converting the screenshot to a Bitmap doesn't work and gives an error:

> AForge.Imaging.UnsupportedImageFormatException: 'Source pixel format
>   is not supported by the filter.'

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width,Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height,gfxScreenshot);
```

I've found a solution which is saving the screenshot in a Jpeg format and reloading it using

```
    System.Drawing.Bitmap sourceImage = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Paulo\source\repos\billellera\billellera\mainscreen.jpg");
```

Of course this is not a good solution, what should i try?

Comment: That statement can't throw an AForge exception.  Best to show the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm sorry, wrong ctrl-c-v, the statement that gives the error is             `Bitmap sourceImageCropped = new ResizeBicubic((int)(sourceImage.Width * 0.6), (int)(sourceImage.Height * 0.6)).Apply(sourceImage);` which just crop the image, but if i remove it the error moves to `ExhaustiveTemplateMatching tm = new ExhaustiveTemplateMatching(0.80f)`; so it's same stuff